# Galois group of the $x^8+8\in\Bbb Q[x]$

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

I have this problem because I think the extension has degree $16$ but I can't decide the group: I think it could be $\Bbb Z_4\times\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2$ but not surely:
First I do complex roots

$$x^8=-8=8e^{\pi i+2k\pi},\;k\in\Bbb Z\;,\;\;and\;then\;\;x_k=8^{1/8}e^{\frac\pi8\left(1+2k\right)},\;k=0,1,2,...,7$$

and I write $w=e^{\pi i/8}\;$ and this is primitive root of order $16$ , and then the roots are $8^{1/8}w^k,\;w=1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15$ .

Next I think maybe  $8^{1/8}\in\Bbb Q(w)$ but this is not possible because $\;\Bbb Q(w)/\Bbb Q\;$ cyclotomic extension and its order $\phi(16)=8$, and $\;\Bbb Q(8^{1/8})/\Bbb Q\;$ also has the order $8$, and then we could get $\;\Bbb Q(8^{1/8})=\Bbb Q(w)\;$ , but the first is real field and the second has non real complex elements.

I had to do trigonometry but it only took me to $\,8^{1/4}\in\Bbb Q(w)\;$ because

$$\frac1{\sqrt2}=\cos\frac\pi4=2\cos^2\frac\pi8-1\implies\cos^2\frac\pi8=\frac{\frac1{\sqrt2}+1}2=\frac{1+\sqrt2}{2\sqrt2=\sqrt8}\implies\cos\frac\pi8=\frac{\sqrt{1+\sqrt2}}{\sqrt[4]8}$$

and I know also

$$w+w^{-1}=w+\overline w=2\,\text{Re}\,w=2\cos\frac\pi8\in\Bbb Q(w)$$

and this is why I get splitting field of degree $16$ :

$$\left[\Bbb Q(w,8^{1/8})\,:\,\Bbb Q\right]=\left[\Bbb Q(w)(8^{1/8}):\Bbb Q(w)\right]\left[\Bbb Q(w)\,:\,\Bbb Q\right]=2\cdot8=16$$

because $\;x^2-\sqrt[4]8\;$ is the minimal polynomial of $\;\sqrt[8]8\;$ over $\;\Bbb Q(w)\;$ .

Now, I know $\;\text{Gal}\,(\Bbb Q(w)\,/\,\Bbb Q)\cong\left(\Bbb Z/16\Bbb Z\right)^*\cong\Bbb Z_4\times\Bbb Z_2\;$ and is cyclotomic extension. Also, it is clearly $\;\Bbb Q(w,8^{1/8})/\Bbb Q\;$ cyclic extension of order two, and now questions

**Question 1** Is there a simpler method to get $\;\sqrt[4]8\in\Bbb Q(w)\;$? It is not hard (only the trigonometry) but it is long and has many calculations and in time of exam perhaps one can use some lemma or theorem...?

**Question 2** What is the $\;\text{Gal}\,(\Bbb Q(w,8^{1/8})\,/\,\Bbb Q)\,?$ Is it really $\;\Bbb Z_4\times \Bbb Z_2\times \Bbb Z_2\;$ or some harder group? I read there are 14 groups of order $16$, and only 5 of them are abelian, so is there some lemma or trick to know the group this time?

**Question 3** Is my work above right? Any correction, suggestion or comments is very much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure $w$ is in your splitting field, so I don't know why you adjoin $w$. I would start out by adjoining $w^2$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling But $ w^2=e^{\pi i/4}=\frac1{\sqrt2}(1+i)\;$ is a primitive root of unit of order $\;8\;$: for what I want that? If I had the polynomial $\;x^8\color{red}-8\;$ then yes, I'd need roots of unit of order eight. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: It seems natural because you obtain your splitting field by adjoining one root and $w^2$.

Comment: The Galois group cannot be abelian. For if it were, then all the intermediate fields would be Galois extensions as well. In particular, we would get the splitting field by simply adjoining a zero of $x^8+8$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Ah, that is interesting. Could then be the semidirect product $\;\Bbb Z_2\rtimes (\Bbb Z_4\times\Bbb Z_2)\;$ ? This is hard, and found the problem in exam. I wonder if there's trick here.

Comment: It doesn’t affect the mathematics in any way, but it might clarify things just a bit to notice that when $\zeta$ is a root of $X^8+8$, then $\zeta^3/2$ is a root of $X^8+2$

Answer (score 1):

Not an elegant answer really, but a few suggestions; there are probably better ways of doing this.

The splitting field is
$\mathbb Q(w^2, w8^{1/8})$. Let's start out by adjoining $w^2$. Since $w^2=(1+i)/\sqrt{2}$, we have that $\mathbb Q(w^2)=\mathbb Q(i,\sqrt{2})$. Thus $f$ now factors $f=(x^4+i8^{1/2})(x^4-i8^{1/2})$.

Since $f$ was irreducible over $\mathbb Q$, the degree of the splitting field is a multiple of $8$, and, in particular, we must adjoin a zero to $\mathbb Q(w^2)$. This gives an extension of degree either $2$ or $4$, and if it were $2$, this would mean that $x^4+i8^{1/2}$ factors into a product of two degree $2$ polynomials over $\mathbb Q(w^2)$. However, this isn't happening; we can factor over $\mathbb C$ and then check that such a factorization would mean that $2^{1/4}\in\mathbb Q(w^2)$, which is clearly not the case because just adjoining $2^{1/4}$ to $\mathbb Q$ is already a degree $4$ extension, which, however, does not contain $i$.

So indeed $[\mathbb Q(w^2, w8^{1/8}):\mathbb Q]=4\cdot 4 = 16$. As for the Galois group: the automorphisms are obtained by mapping $i\mapsto\pm i$, $\sqrt{2}\mapsto\pm\sqrt{2}$ (corresponding to $\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2$ so far), and then we map $w8^{1/8}$ to one of its four conjugates, or if $x^4+i8^{1/2}\mapsto x^{1/4}-i8^{1/2}$, then we must map to one of the four zeros of the other polynomial.

It's not immediately clear (to me) what group that is; also, thanks to Jyrki for pointing out a blunder in an earlier version. Here are a few things we can say right away:

(1) (Jyrki) $G$ is not abelian because our extension has the non-normal (over $\mathbb Q$) intermediate field $\mathbb Q(w8^{1/8})$, so $G$ has a non-normal subgroup;

(2) $G$ has a normal subgroup $H\cong\mathbb Z_4$ with $G/H=\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2$. This follows by considering the intermediate field $\mathbb Q(w^2)$.

---

**Update:** I've got it now, but again it's brute force rather than elegant. Consider the following two automorphisms (I write $R=w8^{1/8}$):
$$
a: i\mapsto i,\quad \sqrt{2}\mapsto -\sqrt{2}, \quad R \mapsto iw^2 R;\\
b: i\mapsto -i, \quad \sqrt{2}\mapsto -\sqrt{2}, \quad R \mapsto R
$$
Then we can check that $a^8=b^2=1$ (and these are the orders), and $ba=a^3b$. Since $b\notin\langle a\rangle$, the elements $a,b$ generate $G$, and the relations we have found are the ones from the presentation of the [semidihedral group of order 16.](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Semidihedral_group:SD16)

Alternatively, we can describe this as the semidirect product $\mathbb Z_8 \rtimes\mathbb Z_2$, with the non-identity element of $\mathbb Z_2$ acting on $\mathbb Z_8$ by sending $1\mapsto 3$; this automorphism has order $2$, so this does define a group action. We can then check that $a=(1,0)$, $b=(0,1)$ satisfy the relations.

Comment: I need to read this with care and I cannot now. Thank you +1

Comment: A lot of good stuff in here, but check the last paragraph. Let $L$ be the splitting field, and $G=Gal(L/\Bbb{Q})$ the Galois group. If $G$ were abelian, then the subgroup $H=Gal(L/\Bbb{Q}(w8^{1/8}))$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. This implies that $\Bbb{Q}(w8^{1/8})$ would already be a normal extension. In particular, it would be the splitting field...

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: That's a good point, thanks! Apparently it was only tedious, not straightforward to "check" that $G$ is abelian.